# Groovy DataSource/BuildConfig can't find class

Tags: grails, datasource, buildconfig

I know this is a really basic question but I'm stuck here and i don't know why. So this is the situation: I am trying to connect My Grails application. I put the .jar in the lib-directory and put this code in the BuildConfig.groovy:

```
 dependencies {
    // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.
    // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.27'
     runtime 'mariadb:mariadb-java-client:1.1.5'
    // runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1100-jdbc41'
}
```

and this in my DataSource.groovy:

```
production {
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "update"
        url = "jdbc:mariadb://localhost/gTunes"
        driverClassName = "org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver"
        username = "root"
        password = ""
        pooled = true
        properties {
            maxActive = -1
            minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=1800000
            timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=1800000
            numTestsPerEvictionRun=3
            testOnBorrow=true
            testWhileIdle=true
            testOnReturn=true
            validationQuery="SELECT 1"
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the error im getting (basically a ClassNotFoundException:

```
Error |
2014-01-21 14:04:56,120 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR pool.ConnectionPool  - Unable to create initial connections of pool.
Message: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
    Line | Method
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by ClassNotFoundException: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
->>  366 | run       in java.net.URLClassLoader$1
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|    355 | run       in     ''
|    354 | findClass in java.net.URLClassLoader
|    425 | loadClass in java.lang.ClassLoader
|    270 | forName . in java.lang.Class
|    262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Error |
2014-01-21 14:04:56,232 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR pool.ConnectionPool  - Unable to create initial connections of pool.
Message: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
    Line | Method
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by ClassNotFoundException: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
->>  366 | run       in java.net.URLClassLoader$1
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|    355 | run       in     ''
|    354 | findClass in java.net.URLClassLoader
|    425 | loadClass in java.lang.ClassLoader
|    270 | forName . in java.lang.Class
|    262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Error |
2014-01-21 14:04:56,382 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR pool.ConnectionPool  - Unable to create initial connections of pool.
Message: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
    Line | Method
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by ClassNotFoundException: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
->>  366 | run       in java.net.URLClassLoader$1
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|    355 | run       in     ''
|    354 | findClass in java.net.URLClassLoader
|    425 | loadClass in java.lang.ClassLoader
|    270 | forName . in java.lang.Class
|    262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Error |
2014-01-21 14:04:56,404 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization
Message: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean
    Line | Method
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateProperties' while setting bean property 'hibernateProperties'; nested excepti
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dia
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error w
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by SQLException: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by ClassNotFoundException: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
->>  366 | run       in java.net.URLClassLoader$1
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|    355 | run       in     ''
|    354 | findClass in java.net.URLClassLoader
|    425 | loadClass in java.lang.ClassLoader
|    270 | forName . in java.lang.Class
|    262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Error |
2014-01-21 14:04:56,461 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing Grails: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean f
Message: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean
    Line | Method
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateProperties' while setting bean property 'hibernateProperties'; nested excepti
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dia
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error w
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by SQLException: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by ClassNotFoundException: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
->>  366 | run       in java.net.URLClassLoader$1
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|    355 | run       in     ''
|    354 | findClass in java.net.URLClassLoader
|    425 | loadClass in java.lang.ClassLoader
|    270 | forName . in java.lang.Class
|    262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Error |
2014-01-21 14:04:56,516 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR [localhost].[/gStore]  - Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsCon
Message: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean
    Line | Method
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateProperties' while setting bean property 'hibernateProperties'; nested excepti
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dia
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error w
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by SQLException: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by ClassNotFoundException: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
->>  366 | run       in java.net.URLClassLoader$1
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|    355 | run       in     ''
|    354 | findClass in java.net.URLClassLoader
|    425 | loadClass in java.lang.ClassLoader
|    270 | forName . in java.lang.Class
|    262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
   Error |
2014-01-21 14:04:56,555 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR core.StandardContext  - Error listenerStart
Error |
2014-01-21 14:04:56,602 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR core.StandardContext  - Context [/gStore] startup failed due to previous errors
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: In which section of `BuildConfig.groovy` have you put `runtime 'mariadb:mariadb-java-client:1.1.5'`?

Comment: Did you try to clean project after putting the *.jar in the lib-directory ? p.s. http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/ref/Command%20Line/clean.html

Comment: clean and refresh dependencies should work

Comment: I can't find `'mariadb:mariadb-java-client:1.1.5'` in maven...?

Comment: Have a look at this mvm repository http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jumpmind.symmetric.jdbc/mariadb-java-client/1.1.1

Comment: @FranGarcía That's 4 versions behind tho, and requires a certain amount of trust ;-)  Looks like emilan is right, and you should download the jar and stick it in lib

Comment: Did a clean, now I'm getting:
    | Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not find artifact mariadb:mariadb:jar:1.1.5 in grailsCentral (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)

Why isn't he lookking in the local folder first?

Comment: @tim_yates you are right!

Answer (score 0):

it looks like version 1.1.5 does not exist in maven repo. You should try it with 1.1.1 and start the application.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the one I use, from Maven therefor without jar — as suggested  in commentaries.

```
dependencies {
    runtime    'org.mariadb.jdbc: mariadb-java-client:1.5.0-RC1'        
    /*1.6.0-SNAPSHOT,,,,1.5.0-RC1,,,1.4.6*/
}
```

Or Jar connection string

```
dependencies {
    runtime    'jdbc: mariadb-java-client:1.5.0-RC1' 
}
```

Or Maven strictly speaking

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
    <version>xxx</version>
</dependency>
```

Please be sure to double check the source doc for such case:

[mariaDB installation methods](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/about-mariadb-connector-j/#installing-the-driver)

[mariaDB jar connector](https://mariadb.com/downloads/connector)